# Matplotlib to set the frequency on xaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to set the frequency of the x axis of my chart with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.plot(vol['BTC'], 'b-', vol['ETH'], 'r-', vol['XRP'], 'g-', vol['BCH'], 'y-')
plt.legend(labels= ['BTC','ETH','XRP','BCH'], fontsize="xx-small")
plt.xticks(rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
start, end = ax.get_xlim()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, 20))
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 3})
```

However, nothing changes and it remains like a bulk of ink as the labels overlaps. 
I would like to lower the frequency of display and reduce the size of the labels.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I tried the following but the chart is empty.

```
My new code:

years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
days = mdates.DayLocator()  # every day
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
vol_index = vol.index

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.array(vol.index), np.array(vol['BTC']))

# format the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)

# round to nearest years.
datemin = pd.to_datetime(np.datetime64(vol.index[0], 'D')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
datemax = pd.to_datetime(np.datetime64(vol.index[-1], 'D') + np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

# format the coords message box
ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.format_ydata = lambda x: '$%1.2f' % x  # format the price.
ax.grid(True)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

This code use the following input:

`np.array(vol['BTC'])`:

```
[0.05498711 0.03454131 0.03454131 0.02293731 0.02191053 0.02191053
 0.01688648 0.02828462 0.02828462 0.02828462 0.03188105 0.03054535
 0.02955679 0.0270898  0.0281818  0.02866918 0.02710031 0.02668099
 0.03404319 0.03670357 0.05311734 0.08663729 0.08663729 0.08339912
 0.08831546 0.08063601 0.07522458 0.06043395 0.06280006 0.06543079
 0.06543079 0.0444152  0.0444152  0.03575803 0.03575803 0.03575803
 0.02870328 0.02870328 0.02870328 0.02870328 0.02835626 0.02263508
 0.02263508 0.02514882 0.0332816  0.02463769 0.0385677  0.0427951
 0.04329788 0.04329788 0.04329788 0.05240083 0.05883257 0.05883257
 0.03162634 0.02906886 0.02765406 0.024522   0.02352016 0.01756594
 0.02030382 0.02030382 0.03326152 0.03601441 0.03601441 0.03250479
 0.04571088 0.06313575 0.07639834 0.07639834 0.0555884  0.05133794
 0.0493664  0.03279575 0.05379169 0.05431873 0.05431873 0.04422756
 0.04649411 0.04825915 0.04584981 0.02741382 0.02741382]
```

`vol.index`:

```
Index(['2019-11-01 23:59:08', '2019-11-02 23:59:08', '2019-11-03 23:59:04',
       '2019-11-04 23:59:12', '2019-11-05 23:59:03', '2019-11-06 23:59:08',
       '2019-11-07 23:59:04', '2019-11-08 23:59:07', '2019-11-09 23:59:06',
       '2019-11-10 23:59:05', '2019-11-11 23:59:03', '2019-11-12 23:59:04',
       '2019-11-13 23:59:06', '2019-11-14 23:59:06', '2019-11-15 23:59:05',
       '2019-11-16 23:59:12', '2019-11-17 23:59:03', '2019-11-18 23:59:10',
       '2019-11-19 23:59:09', '2019-11-20 23:59:06', '2019-11-21 23:59:11',
       '2019-11-22 23:59:05', '2019-11-23 23:59:06', '2019-11-24 23:59:09',
       '2019-11-25 23:59:05', '2019-11-26 23:59:03', '2019-11-27 23:59:04',
       '2019-11-28 23:59:05', '2019-11-29 23:59:04', '2019-11-30 23:59:02',
       '2019-12-01 23:59:06', '2019-12-02 23:59:11', '2019-12-03 23:59:02',
       '2019-12-04 23:59:07', '2019-12-05 23:59:07', '2019-12-06 23:59:08',
       '2019-12-07 23:59:07', '2019-12-08 23:59:06', '2019-12-09 23:59:06',
       '2019-12-10 23:59:06', '2019-12-11 23:59:11', '2019-12-12 23:59:05',
       '2019-12-13 23:59:04', '2019-12-14 23:59:08', '2019-12-15 23:59:07',
       '2019-12-16 23:59:13', '2019-12-17 23:59:10', '2019-12-18 23:59:12',
       '2019-12-19 23:59:09', '2019-12-20 23:59:10', '2019-12-21 23:59:06',
       '2019-12-22 23:59:07', '2019-12-23 23:59:07', '2019-12-24 23:59:13',
       '2019-12-25 23:59:10', '2019-12-26 23:59:11', '2019-12-27 23:59:04',
       '2019-12-28 23:59:05', '2019-12-29 23:59:06', '2019-12-30 23:59:07',
       '2019-12-31 23:59:09', '2020-01-01 23:59:06', '2020-01-02 23:59:02',
       '2020-01-03 23:59:06', '2020-01-04 23:59:03', '2020-01-05 23:59:08',
       '2020-01-06 23:59:07', '2020-01-07 23:59:08', '2020-01-08 23:59:06',
       '2020-01-09 23:59:03', '2020-01-10 23:59:10', '2020-01-11 23:59:02',
       '2020-01-12 23:59:07', '2020-01-13 23:59:04', '2020-01-14 23:59:07',
       '2020-01-15 23:59:04', '2020-01-16 23:59:06', '2020-01-17 23:59:03',
       '2020-01-18 23:59:09', '2020-01-19 23:59:04', '2020-01-20 23:59:04',
       '2020-01-21 23:59:08', '2020-01-22 23:59:04'],
      dtype='object', name='timestamp')
```

`vol`:

```
                      BTC       ETH       XRP       BCH
timestamp                                                  
2019-11-01 23:59:08  0.054987  0.040244  0.029715  0.082026
2019-11-02 23:59:08  0.034541  0.029485  0.026469  0.078933
2019-11-03 23:59:04  0.034541  0.027006  0.026571  0.057731
2019-11-04 23:59:12  0.022937  0.027006  0.026571  0.052057
2019-11-05 23:59:03  0.021911  0.026792  0.023252  0.040931
...                       ...       ...       ...       ...
2020-01-18 23:59:09  0.046494  0.086220  0.066950  0.162209
2020-01-19 23:59:04  0.048259  0.084283  0.066950  0.157251
2020-01-20 23:59:04  0.045850  0.081700  0.064228  0.149919
2020-01-21 23:59:08  0.027414  0.041858  0.042955  0.092721
2020-01-22 23:59:04  0.027414  0.041858  0.042955  0.092721
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my edited answer? Did it help you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [tick locator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# ...
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20))
```

And you can do this, if you want, instead of modifying the rcParams:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',labelsize=3)
```

Comment: I have updated my code as per the edit but it still gives exactly the same as before. Any idea please?

Comment: Oh, can you try specifying a larger value than 20 then? Maybe 100?

Comment: I think that the issue come from the fact my xaxis labels are `date` in which case `20` may not be ok to specify.

Comment: Ah, yes! You're right. Look at this page: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

Comment: I have edited after using the link you sent could you have a look please?

Comment: Sure. Your chart is empty because the "timestamp" column is of type "object" and not a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach where you specify the number of ticks you want instead of the frequency, but you may still find it useful:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange('2017-01', '2020-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')
y = np.random.random(len(x))

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

plt.scatter(df['x'].values, df['y'].values)
ticks = np.arange(x[0], x[-1], (x[-1] - x[0]).astype('timedelta64[D]') / 15)
plt.xticks(ticks, ticks)
plt.gca().tick_params('x', labelrotation=45, labelsize=10)
plt.show()
```

Which gives

[image]

instead of

[image]

---

### Edit

Here is a complete example which uses the given data,

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

BTC = np.array([0.05498711,0.03454131,0.03454131,0.02293731,0.02191053,0.02191053,
                0.01688648,0.02828462,0.02828462,0.02828462,0.03188105,0.03054535,
                0.02955679,0.0270898, 0.0281818, 0.02866918,0.02710031,0.02668099,
                0.03404319,0.03670357,0.05311734,0.08663729,0.08663729,0.08339912,
                0.08831546,0.08063601,0.07522458,0.06043395,0.06280006,0.06543079,
                0.06543079,0.0444152, 0.0444152, 0.03575803,0.03575803,0.03575803,
                0.02870328,0.02870328,0.02870328,0.02870328,0.02835626,0.02263508,
                0.02263508,0.02514882,0.0332816, 0.02463769,0.0385677, 0.0427951,
                0.04329788,0.04329788,0.04329788,0.05240083,0.05883257,0.05883257,
                0.03162634,0.02906886,0.02765406,0.024522,  0.02352016,0.01756594,
                0.02030382,0.02030382,0.03326152,0.03601441,0.03601441,0.03250479,
                0.04571088,0.06313575,0.07639834,0.07639834,0.0555884, 0.05133794,
                0.0493664, 0.03279575,0.05379169,0.05431873,0.05431873,0.04422756,
                0.04649411,0.04825915,0.04584981,0.02741382,0.02741382])

idx = np.array(['2019-11-01 23:59:08', '2019-11-02 23:59:08', '2019-11-03 23:59:04',
                '2019-11-04 23:59:12', '2019-11-05 23:59:03', '2019-11-06 23:59:08',
                '2019-11-07 23:59:04', '2019-11-08 23:59:07', '2019-11-09 23:59:06',
                '2019-11-10 23:59:05', '2019-11-11 23:59:03', '2019-11-12 23:59:04',
                '2019-11-13 23:59:06', '2019-11-14 23:59:06', '2019-11-15 23:59:05',
                '2019-11-16 23:59:12', '2019-11-17 23:59:03', '2019-11-18 23:59:10',
                '2019-11-19 23:59:09', '2019-11-20 23:59:06', '2019-11-21 23:59:11',
                '2019-11-22 23:59:05', '2019-11-23 23:59:06', '2019-11-24 23:59:09',
                '2019-11-25 23:59:05', '2019-11-26 23:59:03', '2019-11-27 23:59:04',
                '2019-11-28 23:59:05', '2019-11-29 23:59:04', '2019-11-30 23:59:02',
                '2019-12-01 23:59:06', '2019-12-02 23:59:11', '2019-12-03 23:59:02',
                '2019-12-04 23:59:07', '2019-12-05 23:59:07', '2019-12-06 23:59:08',
                '2019-12-07 23:59:07', '2019-12-08 23:59:06', '2019-12-09 23:59:06',
                '2019-12-10 23:59:06', '2019-12-11 23:59:11', '2019-12-12 23:59:05',
                '2019-12-13 23:59:04', '2019-12-14 23:59:08', '2019-12-15 23:59:07',
                '2019-12-16 23:59:13', '2019-12-17 23:59:10', '2019-12-18 23:59:12',
                '2019-12-19 23:59:09', '2019-12-20 23:59:10', '2019-12-21 23:59:06',
                '2019-12-22 23:59:07', '2019-12-23 23:59:07', '2019-12-24 23:59:13',
                '2019-12-25 23:59:10', '2019-12-26 23:59:11', '2019-12-27 23:59:04',
                '2019-12-28 23:59:05', '2019-12-29 23:59:06', '2019-12-30 23:59:07',
                '2019-12-31 23:59:09', '2020-01-01 23:59:06', '2020-01-02 23:59:02',
                '2020-01-03 23:59:06', '2020-01-04 23:59:03', '2020-01-05 23:59:08',
                '2020-01-06 23:59:07', '2020-01-07 23:59:08', '2020-01-08 23:59:06',
                '2020-01-09 23:59:03', '2020-01-10 23:59:10', '2020-01-11 23:59:02',
                '2020-01-12 23:59:07', '2020-01-13 23:59:04', '2020-01-14 23:59:07',
                '2020-01-15 23:59:04', '2020-01-16 23:59:06', '2020-01-17 23:59:03',
                '2020-01-18 23:59:09', '2020-01-19 23:59:04', '2020-01-20 23:59:04',
                '2020-01-21 23:59:08', '2020-01-22 23:59:04'], dtype='datetime64[s]')

df = pd.DataFrame({'BTC': BTC})
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(idx)

x = df.index.values.astype('datetime64[D]')
y = df['BTC']

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.plot(x, y)
ticks = np.arange(x[0], x[-1], (x[-1] - x[0]).astype('timedelta64[D]') / 15)
plt.xticks(ticks, ticks)
plt.gca().tick_params('x', labelrotation=90, labelsize=10)
plt.show()
```

This will give you

[image]

Comment: thank you but I am not sure if I can use a scatter plot. Basically my data is a `pd.dataframe` with the index as xaxis and several columns as yaxis (line chart)

Comment: @delalma The scatter plot was just for demonstration, the method is for adjusting the tick labels, it doesn't matter at all what the plot contains

Comment: @delalma Is the dataframe’s index in datetime or integer?

Comment: I have updated the post, the index is also there. It is datetime.

Comment: @delalma The code in my answer will work, you just have to add the line `x = vol.index.values` before `ticks = ...`

Comment: @delalma There was some typecasting I neglected in my previous comment, it should have been `x = vol.index.values.astype('datetime64[D]')` - my apologies. In any case, I have edited my answer to include a complete example which uses the data you supplied